# How does Ruby parse: a.b = B.new a.b.c = C.new?

Tags: ruby, authorize.net

I'm assuming it treats it as

```
a.b = (B.new (a.b.c = C.new))
```

This is the line:

```
request.transactionRequest.payment = PaymentType.new request.transactionRequest.payment.creditCard = CreditCardType.new('4242424242424242','0220','123')
```

https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/

I'm assuming it would treat it as

> request.transactionRequest.payment = ( PaymentType.new ( request.transactionRequest.payment.creditCard = CreditCardType.new('4242424242424242','0220','123') ) )

How would `payment.creditCard` get assigned if `payment` is even set yet? Wouldn't that generate a nil pointer error? Even if it worked, why would you do that to overwrite `payment` when you just set `payment.creditCard`?

Comment: Writing code like this is how you get in trouble. What's the motivation here for having multiple assignments in the course of one line?

Comment: @tadman Are you assuming that I created the Authorize.net page and the code?

Comment: `a.b.c = C.new` can be considered to have the value `C.new` but assigns to the variable as a side effect. I'm pretty sure the code you show will only work if `a.b` is previously defined.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that's where it came from.That external link is just sort of dumped there without explanation.

Comment: That example code is just awful. Floats for monetary values!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing a newline, that's all:

```
request.transactionRequest.payment = PaymentType.new
request.transactionRequest.payment.creditCard = CreditCardType.new('4242424242424242','0220','123')
```

Although the one-line version is valid Ruby syntax, it's also not something you'd do in production code without good cause.

Comment: The one-line version is valid Ruby syntax, but is unlikely to work since it tries to set `request.transactionRequest.payment.creditCard` before `request.transactionRequest.payment` is initialized.

Comment: @Max Yeah, there's a difference between valid syntax and valid code. The former can be parsed, the second can be executed.

Comment: Wow you are right. https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-ruby/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/charge-credit-card.rb#L17 The HTML must have been mangled.